# Laptop's monitor goes black after bios

Tags: laptop, display, external-display

I have a laptop whose monitor reaches bios and then when windows start it goes black.

I connected it via vga to an external monitor and it runs good.

So the monitor should not be burned from what I deduce. Any ideas for what could be wrong or what I could check? I think it gets too hot sometimes, could it be it?

Comment: If there is a sensor that tells the laptop is folded shut,  maybe that is stuck, perhaps turning off the display because it thinks it is closed,

Comment: Check your screen resolution and refresh rate settings, via another monitor.  There's a chance they have got messed up and the display can't handle the settings.

Comment: @infixed then the computer would have gone in sleep mode right? It doesn't quite fit the situation.
Tony68000 I've done all the basics.

Could it be a graphics card(hardware) problem?

Comment: Putting things to sleep is commonly how that is set,  but often going to sleep isn't fast.  Doing housekeeping, update checks, etc.  But often it is possible to set it to operate normally with cover closed for when you are in a docking station with monitors attached

Comment: If there is a thermal shutdown, that should show up as a system (I think) event.   After it does it once, put a monitor back on the machine, then go look through event viewer to see what it did.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the "presentation" button? This is usually `FN` + `F5` or something similar. If you can let me know the laptop make and model I can guide you better.